# Custom sub taxonomy order by

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy

In single categories page, particular parent categories sub-categories display by slug or order wise i will try but something is wrong in my code so please check my code and let me know how is it possible.

```
$term_children = get_term_children( $EM_Category->id, 'event-categories' );
if ( count($term_children) > 0 ) {
    foreach ( $term_children as $child ) {
        $term = get_term_by( 
            'id', 
            $child, 
            'event-categories', 
            array( 
                'orderby' => 'slug',
                'hide_empty' => true
            ) 
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit hard to say what exactly was the point of your code...

First problem that I can see is that you're misusing `get_term_by` function.

This function takes 5 params:

```
get_term_by( $field, $value, $taxonomy, $output, $filter )
```

- **$field** (string) (required) Either 'id', 'slug', 'name', or 'term_taxonomy_id'
- **$value** (string|integer) (required) Search for this term value Default: None
- **$taxonomy** (string) (required) Taxonomy Name category, post_tag, link_category, nav_menu or something custom Default: '' (empty string)
- **$output** (string) (optional) Constant OBJECT, ARRAY_A, or ARRAY_N Default: OBJECT
- **$filter** (string) (optional) default is raw or no WordPress defined filter will applied. Default: 'raw'

And in your code it's used like so:

```
$term = get_term_by( 
    'id', 
    $child, 
    'event-categories', 
    array( 
        'orderby' => 'slug',
        'hide_empty' => true
    ) 
);
```

So first three params are correct, but the last one should be `$output` and you pass something else in there... And even if that array was correct param, it makes no sense to sort in that place...

### So how to get children of a term sorted in alphabetical order?

You can do this easily using [`get_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) function:

```
$term_children = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'event-categories',
    'child_of' => $EM_Category->id,
    'orderby' => 'name'
) );
```